# Running into some problems linking my CSS

Tags: html, css

So I've got down my basic html framework down and some basic CSS to make it look centered and adjust the background color, but I've tried a couple different adjustments and none seem to work properly when linking my CSS.

I've attempted to adjust the path to my CSS, tried to change the encoding between utf-8 and a few other random Windows 'save as' ones, and tried adjusting spacing:

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <!doctype html>
    <html>

    <body>
      <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href=/Computer/C:/Users/JohnDoe/Downloads/Test.css>
    </body>

    </html>
```

And in the .css file:

```
body {
   text-align: center; 
   background: powderblue; 
}
```

Whenever I run my program it just comes out looking like a normal black and white page that is off centered.

Comment: `link` tags shoud be called on `<head>` not on `<body>`...

Comment: Attributes should be quoted and the href value is most certainly incorrect

Comment: “*So I've got down my basic html framework down*” - no, you don’t. Wherever you’re learning from either refresh your memory, or switch to a different tutorial or resource. You have many errors in the html you posted, as pointed out.

Comment: @LucasArbex yea, it's in head on my normal file, i must have accidentally moved it on this one, sorry

Comment: @DavidThomas i've got way more in my actual file, i just tossed the problem part here

Comment: There's no such thing called **Computer** in filesystem

Comment: Why are people downvoting him? It's a legit question to him ...

Comment: #GG4ming: then consider editing your question to post code that represents your situation, otherwise - as you can see below - answers will focus on the obvious mistakes with the coffee in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it would probably be good to read up on building a website. But in the meantime, here are some things you need to fix:

- link elements go in the `<head>`
- link href should be an absolute *server* link (starting with https://...) **or** a relative path
- quote attribute values
- remove stray css at the end of the doc and put in css file

Relative path means it's the path relative to the file being served (for example, "index.html"). So if your index.html file is in `/Computer/C:/Users/JohnDoe` and your css file is in `/Computer/C:/Users/JohnDoe/css/` then the relative file path is `css/Test.css`

Example

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Test.css">
</head>

<body>
  <p>This text appears in the browser</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Well it's in downloads for now because i had to email it from one pc notepad to another for it to send properly. So you the path be Download/Test.css then?

Comment: You need to move it somewhere the html file can read it. Where is your html file?

Comment: I have it set up in a seprate folder on the desktop labelled as "pc test.html". My first test was run on mobile

Comment: take the space out, make it "pc-test.html", then put your css on your desktop. Link to it like `href="Test.css"`

Comment: @GG4ming Are you running a web server on your desktop? How is your mobile device supposed to see anything on your desktop?

Comment: That didnt seem to work. Should i move the html file to my desktop as well?

Comment: @j08691 no i just have them as base files, no servers involved. This is kind of like my first real project test

Comment: @GG4ming just curious, what URL are you using on your mobile device to access this page that's on your (Windows?) desktop? And What is your mobile device?

Comment: @J. Scott Elblein The mobile device is my phone, android Stylo 5. And not using a url, rather an app called QuickEdit for my mobile coding. I just copy/pasted the codes and emailed them to myself and then copy/pasted it to a notepad to "save as" .html or .css

Comment: @J.ScottElblein I'm using chrome to view it, but as far as i know, no links to access it. Just editing the files straight from the desktop and saving to the small folder i had set up

Comment: @GG4ming try this: on your desktop, make a folder named "pctest" (no space, just to simplify it a bit), drop your index.html file with the html code, and the test.css file with the CSS code, into that folder. for the link to the CSS file, just use `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">`. Then double-click that index.html file.

Comment: @J.ScottElblein sorry about the super long delay, we were doing testing yesterday. It works though! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You got a few things going on here:

- First, for externally linked style sheets, the link goes in the `<head>`...`</head>` tags, rather than the `<body>` tags.

Here's a quick reference:
https://www.dummies.com/web-design-development/html5-and-css3/how-to-use-an-external-style-sheet-for-html5-and-css3-programming/

Note the quote:

> The `<link>` tag only occurs in the header. Unlike the `<a>` tag, the `<link>` tag can occur only in the header.

- you're asking to link to an external style sheet, but also including some inline CSS (the `body` stuff you have a t the bottom. Also note that when including inline CSS you need to wrap it in `<style>` tags.
- Lastly, that href path looks odd to me ...

Comment: Well inorganik bellow mentioned the href path so im working on that part, the inline css there isnt actually part of the html file, they're seprate files just have both here to show what is should link to. And yea someone mentioned the <body> part before, i accidently moved it from head when I put in here to ask for help

Comment: @GG4ming I see. In that case you should edit your question to separate the two, so readers like us don't think it's all supposed to be part of the same file.